# Using python for automatically writing data in bag to csv file

Tags: ros, python, rxbag, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I want to write python code to automatically analyse a bag file and write the contents to a csv file (to allow for easy plotting afterwards).
So far I can analyse the topics in the bag file, ...
but I still looking for a tool that can automatically tell me how a message looks like (for instance PoseStamped consist of a header and a pose). I know that this information is in the message definition but I did not find an efficient way yet to get it into python.
Of course I also had a look at rxbag, but I did not immediately found what I need.
Can someone give me a hint?

Thanks,

Tinne

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9706/using-python-for-automatically-writing-data-in-bag-to-csv-file/) by [Tinne De Laet](https://answers.ros.org/users/137/tinne-de-laet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 198 on 2011-04-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[rostopic echo -p](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rostopic#rostopic_echo) may do what you want with no code required.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2011-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can introspect on a message using _slots and _slot_types.  Here are their values for Header.

```
  __slots__ = ['seq','stamp','frame_id']
  _slot_types = ['uint32','time','string']
```

They have different underscores because **slots** is a Python builtin and has special meaning.

```
from std_msgs.msg import Header
for name, type_ in zip(Header.__slots__, Header._slot_types):
     print name, type_
```

prints:

```
seq uint32
stamp time
frame_id string
```

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-04-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might find the info on the [Interoperability](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Interoperability) wiki page helpful (even if not, please consider adding to it if you find something later on that isn't there). In particular it mentions the `BagLoader` class from [starmac_tools](http://www.ros.org/wiki/starmac_tools), which was written mainly for the plotting use case you have in mind. Good Luck!

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) with karma: 2264 on 2011-04-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to figure out the same thing. Last few commands on this page worked perfectly for converting .bag to .csv.

http://wiki.fieldrobot.dk/index.php/FroboMind:Cheat_Sheet

---

Originally posted by [punching](https://answers.ros.org/users/1882/punching/) with karma: 78 on 2012-06-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-06-15**:
I've ticketed the broken link here: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3988 , as it looks fine in preview but is broken here.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A non generic approach is rosbag_analysis (see http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag_analysis).
I just check for some attribute names and I "guess" the type from the attribute name for a very narrow set of message types.

This is bad, but it works... :)

edit: rostopic -p does not do what I want as it works on topics "live" so it may drop messages... rosbag_analysis processes bag files offline using the bag Python API.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2012-06-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1